# How do I scroll content over an image?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library, androiddesignsupport

I'm trying to implement the Play Store header image behaviour, without success.
I was able to have the entire page scrolled, but only along with the `ImageView` inside the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.
I used the [example at the announcement of Android Design Support library](http://android-developers.blogspot.hu/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html). The XML of the activity as of now looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_height="192dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    layout_width="wrap_content" layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed" layout_width="wrap_content"
        layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:src="@android:mipmap/sym_def_app_icon"/>
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" layout_width="wrap_content" layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="New Text"
              android:id="@+id/textView" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I'm pretty sure that something's missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `ScrollView`, you need to wrap your `AppBarLayout` inside a `CoordinatorLayout`.

You would also need to put `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` on the `ViewGroup` immediately following the `AppBarLayout` that is the main page content.

[Here's a layout from Chris Banes' cheesesquare sample app.](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_detail.xml)

Comment: I replaced the ScrollView. Which View do I put the property in - by below, you mean in 2D space (which also is the order of code right now), or in nesting?

Comment: Updated answer.  Put it on the view that has your page content that is below the app bar.  Check the sample layout in the link, the attribute is on the `NestedScrollView` that is immediately after the `AppBarLayout`.